# How can I change the style in TS-File?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mat-table

I have written a service in which different colors are defined. Now I would like to set a different background for my columns. Using the `<th>` tag it is not possible, because immediately both columns get the same colors.

My Code:

**change-color-service**

```
export class ChangeColorService {

  public defaultStyles = {
    firstDesignBackgroundColor: '#25a1b1',
    secondDesignBackgroundColor: '#c3c0c0',
  };

  sharedStyleSource = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
  public sharedStyle = this.sharedStyleSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  newStyle(obj: any) {
    this.defaultStyles[obj.name] = obj.value;
    console.log('defaultStyles:', this.defaultStyles);
    this.sharedStyleSource.next(obj);
  }
}
```

**my-component**

```
  public myArray = [
    { attribute: 'firstColumn', name: 'Firstname'},
    { attribute: 'secondColumn', name: 'Lastname'},
  ];

ngAfterViewInit() {
    changeFirst('firstColumn');
    changeFirst('secondColumn');
  }

public changeFirst(attributeToChange: any) {
    const displayedColumn = this.displayedColumns.find((dc) => dc.attribute === attributeToChange);
    if (displayedColumn && displayedColumn !== null) {
      displayedColumn.attribute = this.changeColorService.defaultStyles.firstDesignBackgroundColor;
    }
  }

public changeSecond(attributeToChange: any) {
    const displayedColumn = this.displayedColumns.find((dc) => dc.attribute === attributeToChange);
    if (displayedColumn && displayedColumn !== null) {
      displayedColumn.attribute = this.changeColorService.defaultStyles.secondDesignBackgroundColor;
    }
  }
```

It does not seem to work that way. Can you tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: For each column another background-color or only two different background-colors and then repeat over and over?

Comment: Right, I want to assign a different background color to each column.

Comment: From service... firstDesignBackgroundColor for firstColumn and secondDesignBackgroundColor for secondColumn

Comment: and which color you want for the third column?

Comment: I only have two. See Array. If I had a third or fourth column, I want to use the colours I define in the service.

Comment: okay, but in the second comment you say :"Right, I want to assign a different background color to each column.". Does it have to be with a service or not?

Comment: Yes with the service. Have you a idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, but not with *your's* service!

I have create a method `changeColor()` with a parameter. The parameter is the index of the tables-output (in my example, the index from the alphabet array). So the method `changeColor()`
check against the index, if the *index* is **even** (return color-one) or **odd** (return color-two) to alternate the color every time.

The color can be set in the `.ts` file.

```
public changeColor(index: number): string {
  if (index % 2 == 0 ) { // if is even
    return "#25a1b1"; // first color
  } else if (index % 2 == 1 ) { // if is odd
    return "#c3c0c0"; // second color
  } 
}
```

The `background-color` in the HTML-file I define as follow and set after the `background-color`-CSS attribut the method `changeColor()` where return one of the both colors:

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of alphabet; index as i">
    <td style="background-color:{{ changeColor(i) }};"> {{ element.name }} </td>
</tr>
```

Have a look at my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gun3t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)